# Display datatables through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, datatables

I'm trying to display a datatables table by an ajax call.

There is a `sales.jsp`, and it has 2 inputs start-date and end-date. There is another `report.jsp` that reads its requests' parameters and calculates a data and display them in a datatable(jQuery-plugin)

The folder structure of the used files and folders, is as follows and the JS libraries are in `js` folder:

```
js
admin
|--report.jsp
|--sales
   |--sales.jsp
```

The AJAX on `sales.jsp` is as follows:

```
function getReport() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var startdate = document.forms["cat-sales"]["start-date"].value;
    var enddate = document.forms["cat-sales"]["end-date"].value;
    var url = "../report.jsp?start-date=" + startdate + "&end-date=" + enddate;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
            document.getElementById("report-view").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
        }
    };
    try {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } catch (e) {
        alert("unable to connect to server");
    }
}
```

I tried adding the css links and js src's to the report.jsp but then it gave errors on the browser's console and I figured that it was because the two files (`sales.jsp` and `report.jsp`) are on two different levels.

Then I added the link paths relative to `sales.jsp` and it gave CSS errors. (Eg:The headers looked crooked)

How can I achieve this correctly?

The `report.jsp` is as follows:

```
<%@page import="java.lang.String" %>
<%@page import="java.util.List" %> 
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page import="Model.CategorySales" %>
<%@page import="Model.Report" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Date" %>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="windows-1252" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Report</title>

</head>
<body>
<% 
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date startDate = new Date(sdf.parse(request.getParameter("start-date")).getTime());
        Date endDate = new Date(sdf.parse(request.getParameter("end-date")).getTime());

        Report report = new CategorySales(startDate, endDate);

        List<List> data = report.getData();
        String[] fields = report.getOutputfields();

        if (null != data && null != fields) {
            int fieldCount = report.getOutputfieldCount();
%>
<table id="table_report" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        %>
        <th><%=fields[i]%>
        </th>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <%
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            List<String> column = (ArrayList) data.get(i);
    %>
    <tr>
        <%
            for (int j = 0; j < column.size(); j++) {
        %>
        <td><%=column.get(j)%>
        </td>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
    </tbody>

</table>
<%
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out the answer after trying out a lot of things.

The solution to get the datatables functionality, was to call the `$("#table_report").DataTable();` after it is added to the main document.

```
function getReport() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var startdate = document.forms["cat-sales"]["start-date"].value;
    var enddate = document.forms["cat-sales"]["end-date"].value;
    var url = "../report.jsp?start-date=" + startdate + "&end-date=" + enddate;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
            document.getElementById("report-view").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 

            //--------------- Added this line ---------------
            $("#table_report").DataTable();
        }
    };
    try {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } catch (e) {
        alert("unable to connect to server");
    }
}
```

The CSS error was fixed by setting the proper order of the CSS files. Basically it had some overlapping components.